# Using Pandas correlation matrix for 12 np.arrays with np.dot as formula

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to solve a puzzle here. I have twelve np.array items, which are first mentioned as a list, then transformed into an array (see full code below until first note). From these 12 variables, I want to make a 12x12 correlation items, in which these items are being put through [np.dot](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) for all 144 values in the matrix:

```
np.dot(var_1,var_2)
```

In the first item, it would be variables *d_normal* and *d_normal*, followed by *d_normal* and *d_redraw*, so on and so forth. I have looked into making a correlation matrix using Pandas, and I noticed the following in the [df.corr documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.corr.html):

> **callable: callable with input two 1d ndarrays** and returning a float. Note that the returned matrix from corr will have 1 along the diagonals and will be symmetric regardless of the callable’s behavior.

I am unsure if I'm on the right track with this, but I cannot seem to figure it out. As of now I have a correlation matrix that (I assume according to documentation of df.corr) uses the Spearman method, and I am stuck on making a callable definition that follows my np.dot 'formula'. Also, I understand the correlation matrix is not fully shown due to the many columns; is there a way to still force this?

For full clarity, below is both my code and my output. If anyone can help, that'd be lovely as I'm stuck on the documentation!

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d_normal = ['1.00', '1.00', '0.90', '0.60', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.10', '0.40', '0.70', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00',
            '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.10', '0.40', '0.70', '1.00', '1.00', '0.90', '0.60', '0.00']
d_redraw = ['1.00', '1.00', '0.90', '0.60', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.20', '0.40', '0.70', '1.00', '1.00', '0.10',
            '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.20', '0.40', '0.70', '1.00', '1.00', '0.90', '0.60', '0.00']
d_noise = ['0.80', '0.80', '0.70', '0.40', '0.00', '0.80', '0.80', '0.00', '0.20', '0.50', '0.80', '0.80', '0.00',
           '0.00', '0.80', '0.80', '0.80', '0.00', '0.20', '0.50', '0.80', '0.80', '0.70', '0.40', '0.00']
d_noise_blur = ['0.96', '0.96', '0.84', '0.48', '0.00', '0.96', '0.96', '0.00', '0.24', '0.60', '0.96', '0.96', '0.00',
                '0.00', '0.96', '0.96', '0.96', '0.00', '0.24', '0.60', '0.96', '0.96', '0.84', '0.48', '0.00']
n_normal = ['1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00',
            '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1.00']
n_redraw = ['1.00', '0.70', '0.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.70', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.70', '1.00',
            '0.70', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.70', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.70', '1.00']
n_noise = ['0.80', '0.50', '0.00', '0.00', '0.80', '0.80', '0.80', '0.50', '0.00', '0.80', '0.80', '0.50', '0.80',
           '0.50', '0.80', '0.80', '0.00', '0.50', '0.80', '0.80', '0.80', '0.00', '0.00', '0.50', '0.80']
n_noise_blur = ['0.96', '0.60', '0.00', '0.00', '0.96', '0.96', '0.96', '0.60', '0.00', '0.96', '0.96', '0.60', '0.96',
                '0.60', '0.96', '0.96', '0.00', '0.60', '0.96', '0.96', '0.96', '0.00', '0.00', '0.60', '0.96']
w_normal = ['1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '0.80', '0.20', '0.80',
            '0.20', '0.80', '0.60', '0.40', '0.60', '0.40', '0.60', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00']
w_redraw = ['1.00', '0.40', '1.00', '0.40', '1.00', '1.00', '0.40', '1.00', '0.40', '1.00', '0.80', '0.40', '1.00',
            '0.40', '0.80', '0.60', '0.60', '0.80', '0.60', '0.60', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00']
w_noise = ['0.80', '0.20', '0.80', '0.20', '0.80', '0.80', '0.20', '0.80', '0.20', '0.80', '0.60', '0.20', '0.80',
           '0.20', '0.60', '0.40', '0.40', '0.60', '0.40', '0.40', '0.00', '0.80', '0.00', '0.80', '0.00']
w_noise_blur = ['0.96', '0.24', '0.96', '0.24', '0.96', '0.96', '0.24', '0.96', '0.24', '0.96', '0.72', '0.24', '0.96',
                '0.24', '0.72', '0.48', '0.48', '0.72', '0.48', '0.48', '0.00', '0.96', '0.00', '0.96', '0.00']
d_normal = np.array(d_normal, dtype=float)
d_redraw = np.array(d_redraw, dtype=float)
d_noise = np.array(d_noise, dtype=float)
d_noise_blur = np.array(d_noise_blur, dtype=float)
n_normal = np.array(n_normal, dtype=float)
n_redraw = np.array(n_redraw, dtype=float)
n_noise = np.array(n_noise, dtype=float)
n_noise_blur = np.array(n_noise_blur, dtype=float)
w_normal = np.array(w_normal, dtype=float)
w_redraw = np.array(w_redraw, dtype=float)
w_noise = np.array(w_noise, dtype=float)
w_noise_blur = np.array(w_noise_blur, dtype=float)


# Code for creating the correlation matrix using np.dot method.
def correlation_matrix():
    print(np.dot(d_normal, d_redraw)) # This is done as a test/example to show how the very top left value should look like.
    data = {'d_normal': d_normal,
            'd_redraw': d_redraw,
            'd_noise': d_noise,
            'd_noise_blur': d_noise_blur,
            'n_normal': n_normal,
            'n_redraw': n_redraw,
            'n_noise': n_noise,
            'n_noise_blur': n_noise_blur,
            'w_normal': w_normal,
            'w_redraw': w_redraw,
            'w_noise': w_noise,
            'w_noise_blur': w_noise_blur,
            }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['d_normal', 'd_redraw', 'd_noise', 'd_noise_blur', 'n_normal', 'n_redraw',
                                     'n_noise', 'n_noise_blur', 'w_normal', 'w_redraw', 'w_noise', 'w_noise_blur'])
    corr = df.corr() # in between the brackets I assume to make a callable definition that uses np.dot, but I don't
                                     know how this definition would look like with twelve variables and 144 combinations...
    print(corr)


correlation_matrix()
```

**Output:**

```
11.68
              d_normal  d_redraw   d_noise  ...  w_redraw   w_noise  w_noise_blur
d_normal      1.000000  0.682099  0.668346  ...  0.100367  0.133806      0.133806
d_redraw      0.682099  1.000000  0.990601  ... -0.031988 -0.044149     -0.044149
d_noise       0.668346  0.990601  1.000000  ... -0.062664 -0.070807     -0.070807
d_noise_blur  0.668346  0.990601  1.000000  ... -0.062664 -0.070807     -0.070807
n_normal      0.157401  0.045736  0.084672  ...  0.089596  0.126668      0.126668
n_redraw     -0.037127 -0.127794 -0.098209  ...  0.133475  0.148607      0.148607
n_noise      -0.012338 -0.107866 -0.076365  ...  0.130771  0.149145      0.149145
n_noise_blur -0.012338 -0.107866 -0.076365  ...  0.130771  0.149145      0.149145
w_normal      0.220358  0.007418 -0.007724  ...  0.938153  0.968002      0.968002
w_redraw      0.100367 -0.031988 -0.062664  ...  1.000000  0.987826      0.987826
w_noise       0.133806 -0.044149 -0.070807  ...  0.987826  1.000000      1.000000
w_noise_blur  0.133806 -0.044149 -0.070807  ...  0.987826  1.000000      1.000000

[12 rows x 12 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution! I've made a new function with the formula in it, and only called that formula by only mentioning the functions name, no placeholders. I've also cleaned up the code in the meanwhile, so here is the following code and output. I was only unable to resolve the fact that the correlation matrix is not fully shown, so if anyone can help that'd be lovely! Cheers!

**Code:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

d_normal = np.array(['1.00', '1.00', '0.90', '0.60', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.10', '0.40', '0.70', '1.00', '0.00',
                     '0.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.10', '0.40', '0.70', '1.00', '1.00', '0.90', '0.60',
                     '0.00'], dtype=float)
d_redraw = np.array(['1.00', '1.00', '0.90', '0.60', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.20', '0.40', '0.70', '1.00', '1.00',
                     '0.10', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.20', '0.40', '0.70', '1.00', '1.00', '0.90', '0.60',
                     '0.00'], dtype=float)  # Handmatige wijziging gezien verdikken van een stroke handmatig gaat.
d_noise = [element - 0.2 for element in d_normal]
d_noise_blur = [(element - 0.2) * 1.2 for element in d_normal]
n_normal = np.array(['1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00',
                     '1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.00',
                     '1.00'], dtype=float)
n_redraw = np.array(['1.00', '0.70', '0.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.70', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.70',
                     '1.00',  '0.70', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.70', '1.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '0.00', '0.70',
                     '1.00'], dtype=float)  # Handmatige wijziging gezien verdikken van een stroke handmatig gaat.
n_noise = [element - 0.2 for element in n_normal]
n_noise_blur = [element - 0.2 for element in n_normal]
w_normal = np.array(['1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00', '0.80', '0.20',
                     '0.80',  '0.20', '0.80', '0.60', '0.40', '0.60', '0.40', '0.60', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00',
                     '0.00'], dtype=float)
w_redraw = np.array(['1.00', '0.40', '1.00', '0.40', '1.00', '1.00', '0.40', '1.00', '0.40', '1.00', '0.80', '0.40',
                     '1.00',   '0.40', '0.80', '0.60', '0.60', '0.80', '0.60', '0.60', '0.00', '1.00', '0.00', '1.00',
                     '0.00'], dtype=float)  # Handmatige wijziging gezien verdikken van een stroke handmatig gaat.
w_noise = [element - 0.2 for element in w_normal]
w_noise_blur = [element - 0.2 for element in w_normal]


def np_dot_formula(x, y):
    formula = np.dot(x, y)
    return formula


def correlation_matrix():
    data = {'d_normal': d_normal,
            'd_redraw': d_redraw,
            'd_noise': d_noise,
            'd_noise_blur': d_noise_blur,
            'n_normal': n_normal,
            'n_redraw': n_redraw,
            'n_noise': n_noise,
            'n_noise_blur': n_noise_blur,
            'w_normal': w_normal,
            'w_redraw': w_redraw,
            'w_noise': w_noise,
            'w_noise_blur': w_noise_blur,
            }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['d_normal', 'd_redraw', 'd_noise', 'd_noise_blur', 'n_normal', 'n_redraw',
                                     'n_noise', 'n_noise_blur', 'w_normal', 'w_redraw', 'w_noise', 'w_noise_blur'])
    corr = df.corr(np_dot_formula)
    print(corr)


correlation_matrix()
```

**Output:**

```
              d_normal  d_redraw  d_noise  ...  w_redraw  w_noise  w_noise_blur
d_normal         1.000    11.680     8.98  ...      9.04    5.460         5.460
d_redraw        11.680     1.000     8.34  ...     10.72    5.640         5.640
d_noise          8.980     8.340     1.00  ...      5.80    3.780         3.780
d_noise_blur    10.776    10.008     8.76  ...      6.96    4.536         4.536
n_normal         7.800     8.900     5.20  ...      8.80    5.400         5.400
n_redraw         9.060    11.000     5.62  ...     11.60    6.660         6.660
n_noise          5.120     5.560     3.52  ...      5.56    3.720         3.720
n_noise_blur     5.120     5.560     3.52  ...      5.56    3.720         3.720
w_normal         8.140     8.980     5.46  ...     11.92    8.720         8.720
w_redraw         9.040    10.720     5.80  ...      1.00    8.680         8.680
w_noise          5.460     5.640     3.78  ...      8.68    1.000         7.040
w_noise_blur     5.460     5.640     3.78  ...      8.68    7.040         1.000

[12 rows x 12 columns]

Process finished with exit code 0
```